# Python 3.4; making 1 line generator that returns True or False

Tags: python, boolean, generator

```
points = {
    'ironing': 3,
    'making diner': 5,
    'fighting': -6
    }

work = ["fighting", "making diner", "ironing"]
```

I need to make a 1 line long function called, say `good_or_bad(work)` that has to go through work and has to than check the points and if the points are less than -5 it has to return False otherwise it returns True.

In that instance it will return False

Comment: Anything you tried yourself that you want to share?

Comment: why 1 line only? also it has to take `points` as input to compute anything - you don't want to use globals, but do you prefer to initialize it once (=> a class) or explicitly pass it to the function each time (=> function argument)?

Comment: True/False is evaluated for each value in `points` and then returns False if at least 1 item is `< -5`? Or for a sum or average or other reduction of all points for particular `work`?

Comment: I tried return bool(abs(i) if i <= -5 else False for i in work) but uf course it doesn't work.
1 line because it is my homework :)
Points is just a global set, I want a function argument. If 1 item is < -5 it returns False.

Answer (score 1):

def good_or_bad(work):
    return bool([i for i in work if points[i] >= -5])

I figured it out, that's one way to do it... it returns False when the list is empty and that is when i is grater than value of points.